# How to get absolute DOM path of html element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm having problems with html DOM.

How do I get the value from this path:

`html body div table tbody tr td table tbody tr td table tbody tr td table tbody tr td form table tbody tr td`

I can only find stuff like `getElementbyID/tag/name/class` etc.

How do I get the absolute DOM 'path' of the `td` element (let's say the 3rd cell of the second row in that table)? 
I've been looking everywhere but cannot find a simple answer without ID/Class etc involved.

Comment: The reason i don't use ID's is because i'm writing a script for a asp.net page and the ID's are not static but change often, so that's the reason i can't use ID's

Comment: It's some browsergame and i want to automate certain stuff

Comment: If you need such a path to find a specific element you must have done something wrong. Why is the selector so enormous? For example, why are there `TR`'s in it? A `TD` is always wrapped by a `TR` as a `TR` is always wrapped by a table. You could shorten the selector to about three to four elements and achieve exactly the same. Also I don't understand whether you want to get an element for that selector or if you want to get such a selector for a specific element.

Comment: If the IDs are changing, use static classes on the columns instead.

Comment: well: table#tblMarket tbody tr td#showmarketprice_3204311.right

so i need to iterate through all the rows in that table with ID "tblMarket" and check the value of the sixth td

Comment: …as Christian already stated you really should read something about CSS selectors. `table#tblMarket tbody tr td#showmarketprice_3204311.right` == `#tblMarket #showmarketprice_3204311.right`!!!

Comment: but the problem is these ID's change every 10 mins, i can't predict the ID number of it

Comment: Using jQuery it's super simple: `$('td:nth-child(6)', '#tblMarket')` will return an array of all of the 6th TDs in the table.

Comment: Thank you i will try that and sorry if this question was really noob :)

Comment: Don't be sorry at all, every question is valid. And now you've learnt about efficient selectors!

Answer (score 3):

You could use querySelector(), [but it doesn't have great support](http://caniuse.com/queryselector)...

```
var elem = document.querySelector('html body div table tbody tr td table tbody tr td table tbody tr td table tbody tr td form table tbody tr td');
```

Otherwise just use a library that allows you to use CSS selectors, such as jQuery.

```
var $elem = $('html body div table tbody tr td table tbody tr td table tbody tr td table tbody tr td form table tbody tr td');
```

By the way, selecting like this is *horrible* for performance. Absolutely terrible. Have a read up on [CSS selectors](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/) to learn why.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer i apreciate that, i'll inform myself on jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

First, consider whether you do really need full paths. Referring to IDs or classes is more robust as they have less moving parts.

If full paths are what you need, you may wish to use XPath, as it's specifically designed for finding elements by path.

Here's a [simple cross browser XPath library](https://github.com/andrejpavlovic/xpathjs) - there are many others.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may want something like this:

For the following sample HTML,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="findit.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Welcome to my ASP.net site!</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="h440292">
      <table>
        <!-- tbody omitted, but some (all?) browsers add it -->
        <tr>
          <td>junk</td>
          <td>junk</td>
          <td>junk</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>junk</td>
          <td>junk</td>
          <td>pick me!</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

this jQuery code will find the cell that says "pick me!"

```
$(function () {
    var $resultCell = $("body")
        .children("div").eq(1)
        .children("table")

        // Note I have to add this even though
        // I omitted the tbody in the HTML markup
        .children("tbody") 
        .children("tr").eq(1)
        .children("td").eq(2);
    alert($resultCell.text());
});
```

If performance becomes a problem, you may need to resort to doing something similar using the native DOM methods.

Answer (score 0):

I am playing with this idea. I want to be able to find any node on a page (using a headless browser). Trying to build an absolute node path I created a recursive function, works but I am finding it is not completely unique which is annoying. On here for example, each post is templated so selecting text in the third response will reveal the same node path up the HTML tag as the first post

```
const buildPath = (node) => {
  console.log(node);
  if(node.tagName !== "HTML") {
    path.unshift(node.tagName.toLowerCase())
    buildPath(node.parentNode)
  }
};
const path = [];
builtPath(<start node>);
document.querySelector(path.join(" "))
```

but this is where I am stuck now. Some things don't have any specific classes or names or ids to add to that. I may need to capture the innertext or innerhtml and try to match that. Kinda annoying. I suppose you could load like D3 and inject an incremental ID as data but then the site can't change at all, which may be true for this method too but I would think less so.

Comment: Is your solution working ? Seems like from what you described that you are halfway there.